# Angular/node application setup/scaffolding

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have started to use angular with bower to manage some dependencies and gulp as a task runner. I asked a friend to clone and test my app today and he ran into some issues with setting up my app when it comes to installing dependencies. 
I had him npm install and bower install but I was assuming that he had bower and gulp installed globally.
Do bower and gulp need to be installed locally and added to the package.json? 
given the fact that if you install it via package.json, it puts the executable in ./node_modules/.bin/bower
so you cant type bower install.
What is the best way of handling this.
Thanks

Comment: Is he on windows?  He probable does not have NODE_PATH pointing to his global node_modules directory.

Comment: @Cerad maybe I didn't ask my question correctly but he doesn't have a problem running the app when installing gulp and bower globally but why do I have to make that assumption that he needs to do that. They both seem like dependencies to me and why cant they be added and used as local dependencies